# Reshape function output size is unknown

Tags: matlab, compilation, reshape, matlab-coder

I am using Matlab coder to compile some **.m** files into C static library. In the function below, I am getting the following errors:

```
 function net = mlpunpak(net, w)
    nin = net.nin;
    nhidden = net.nhidden;
    nout = net.nout;

    mark1 = nin*nhidden;
    net.w1 = reshape(w(1:mark1), nin, nhidden);          % Error1 ***
    mark2 = mark1 + nhidden;
    net.b1 = reshape(w(mark1 + 1: mark2), 1, nhidden);   % Error2 ***
    mark3 = mark2 + nhidden*nout;
    net.w2 = reshape(w(mark2 + 1: mark3), nhidden, nout);% Error3 ***
    mark4 = mark3 + nout;
    net.b2 = reshape(w(mark3 + 1: mark4), 1, nout);      % Error4 ***
```

> Error1: *Dimension 1 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the
>   right ([10 x 8] ~= [:? x :?]).* Error2: *Dimension 1 is fixed on the
>   left-hand side but varies on the right ([8 x 1] ~= [:? x :?]).*
>   Error3: *Dimension 1 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the
>   right ([8 x 1] ~= [:? x :?]).* Error4: *Dimension 2 is fixed on the
>   left-hand side but varies on the right ([1 x 1] ~= [1 x :?]).*

The value of the variables are **nin=10**, **nhidden=8**, **nout=1** and this function overwrites the fileds of the **net**. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you gave the fields `w1, b1, w2, b2` the fixed dimensions somewhere. In this case, you are using a `variable-size array` as input of `reshape`, that causes the problem. Have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/restrictions-on-variable-sizing-in-toolbox-functions-supported-for-code-generation.html).

UPDATE: ok, i think i solved the errors. In the Overview tab of Matlab coder, i tried to define the fields as matrix of double with `unbounded` dimensions. And whoops, `Code generation successful: View report` :-)

Btw, at the Error 2, i think it's your fault, since the output of `reshape` here should be `1x8`, you have to check it yourself regarding to your algorithm.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't define the field as this function is not the entry- file of my project. As you guessed, I somehow had set nout and nin to some fixed values in the entry-file. I defined them as inputs to the function as you suggested and it worked just fine!

Comment: then maybe you can find some hints here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/defining-variable-size-data-for-code-generation.html